# iPad app, how to show a uiviewcontroller on top of an uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

Basically this is my situation and don't want to use splitview.
I've a viewbased app, on a side of the main view i've to show a viewcontroller subclass but i don't know how to do it.

Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Apple doesn't recommend it (at least on the iPhone), you can always access the view controller's view and manually add it. Like this (in MainViewController.m):

```
[self.view addSubView:self.secondaryViewController.view];
```